# How do I make an HTML Button perform an Electron JS Function

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm making an electron application, which is simply a HTML Website that I wanted to try and integrate into an application. What would it take to make the  tag with id "createbutton" perform a JS Function in electron, like createprojectwindow()?

main.js:

```
//Launch Main Part of the Program
let mainWindow;
let createWindow;

app.on("ready", function() {
    console.log("Creating new Session");
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        "minWidth" : 800,
        "minHeight": 600
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true,
    }));

    console.log("Creating Menus");
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mienu);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});
function createProjectWindow () {
    console.log("Creating New Project")
    
    createWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400, 
        height: 400,
    });
    createWindow.setMenu(null);
    createWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "./src/createproject.html"),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true,
    }));


}
```

index.html:

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="navlink" id="logo"><a><img id="logoimg" src="Assets/Images/smallInsert.png"></a></li>
                <li class="navlink greyhover" id="myproj"><a>My Projects</a></li>
                <li class="navlink greyhover" id="import"><a>Import</a></li>
                <li class="navlink greyhover" id="test"><a>Test Site</a></li>
                <li class="navlink greyhover" id="create"><a id="createbutton">Create New Project</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To interact with main.js from index.html, you need ipcmain and ipcrenderer

In main.js

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');
ipcMain.on('ABCD', (event, arg) => {/* do something */});
```

In an index.html script

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
let data = /*some data*/;
whenSomethingHappens => {ipcRenderer.send('ABCD', data);}
```

these sources may help further:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/537/how-to-execute-a-function-of-the-main-process-inside-the-renderer-process-in-electron-framework

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate between main and renderer process. You need to use IPC API.

You can approach your goal like this.

`main.js`

```
    const {ipcMain} = require('electron');

    ... 

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        "minWidth" : 800,
        "minHeight": 600,
        "webPreferences": {
             "nodeIntegration": true; // Should be set to use any NodeAPI on renderer process
        }
    });
    ...
    ipcMain.on('create-project-window', (_) => { createProjectWindow()});
```

`index.html`

```
<script>
     function onClickSth() {
          const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
          ipcRenderer.send('create-project-window');
     }     
</script>
```